# Stop arrow keys typing letters in vim insert mode

Tags: bash, terminal, vim, console, terminal.app

When I hit the arrow keys in insert mode I get characters instead of navigation:

[image: Pressing arrow keys types characters]

I'd like to be able to use the arrow keys to navigate.

## Note:

I recently upgraded to macOS Sierra. Maybe something about the terminal changed, because that must have been about the time this problem started.

---

## Things I've tried

I have `set nocompatible` in my `~/.vimrc` ([vimrc pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Zuu5eRwg)), I am using pathogen and here is my `~/.vim/bundle` directory:

```
YouCompleteMe/
emmet-vim/
nerdtree/
node/
vim-airline/
vim-markdown/
```

The problem only started recently, can't remember the cause.

Some recommend `:set term=builtin_ansi`, and this fixes the problem but removes all my colors.

---

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 29 2016 12:51:13)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-2290
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
```

See http://pastebin.com/5z1HbpqW for the whole output.

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

and in vim:

```
:set compatible?
nocompatible

:set term?
term=xterm-256color
```

Comment: There are many [proposed fixes on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell).

Comment: @Deltik I know, none of them worked for me.

Comment: In the article you link to, in "Solution 5" it says that `nocompatible` is the default. Did you try setting it to `compatible`?

Comment: Looks like your TTimeoutLen is set to 10 in your vimrc file. Try upping that to like 1000 and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 how? `:set TTimeoutLen` says no such option

Comment: I edited my comment, it's in your vimrc file. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Doesn't make a differnece

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems on multiple ubutnu machines (16.04 LTS). And none of the soultions worked for me, but then i just did one easy thing. I updated vim via `sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vim` and voila, it worked.